# How can I clone a local git repo to github?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a few git repos on a local server and I want to synchronise them with Github for remote access.

How do I clone these local repos to Github?

After this, is it just a case of assigning the github repo as a remote of the local server repo?

Answer (score 2):

Just create your repo on GitHub, then add GitHub as a remote and push the branches you want to push:

```
git remote add github git@github.com:user/repo.git
git push github master
```